# C++ reverse_iterator Alternatives

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, iterator

I am attempting to write a two-pass algorithm incorporating some legacy code. I want to move through a particular container twice, once in order and once in reverse order. Obviously, my first thought was to use an `iterator` and a `reverse_iterator`, but strangely the designers of the container class I'm using did not see fit to define a working `reverse_iterator` for the container (`reverse_iterators` here cannot be dereferenced like `iterators` can be). I already have an algorithm that requires a `reverse_iterator`.

My thought is to use the first pass iterator for the first part of the algorithm, and as I perform the algorithm `push_front` the items into a new container, then iterate through the new container. This will take up memory, which isn't critical in my application, but made me wonder: are there any cleaner alternatives to `reverse_iterators` in C++, or should I take the time to rework my algorithm using only forward `iterators`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to iterate over the elements of a container in reverse order, you don't necessarily need to use a reverse iterator.

If the container has bidirectional iterators, then you can use ordinary iterators and use `--it` to iterate from `end()` to `begin()` instead of using `++it` to iterate from `begin()` to `end()`.

Since this is a bit tricky, you can use the `std::reverse_iterator` wrapper to convert an ordinary iterator into a reverse iterator (this basically swaps `++` and `--` and encapsulates the trickery required to get this to work).

If the container doesn't have bidirectional iterators then that means it's impossible to iterate over the elements of the container in reverse order, in which case you would need either to rewrite your algorithm or to use a different container.

Any container that has bidirectional iterators, it *should* provide reverse iterator functionality; this is part of the STL and C++ Standard Library "Container" concept.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like the iterator is bidirectional. The class actually uses `std::reverse_iterator` to implement its `reverse_iterator`, but when I try to use it and dereference it, I get a compiler error.

Comment: @Zeke:  You'll have to post the code you are using and the exact compiler errors; otherwise, it's kind of hard to help.  :(

Comment: @James: Fair enough. I think I have the `--it` idea working, but do you have any suggestions for the `for` loop condition? I'd like to use `for (--it; it != end; --it)` but then I'll miss the last item. Can I modify the condition or do I need to include the loop code after the loop body has ended?

Comment: @James: In the above code, `it` is set to `.end()` and `end` is set to `.begin()`.

Comment: @Zeke:  That's the tricky part that the `std::reverse_iterator` template helps with.  :-)  Anyway, you need `for (auto loop_it = end(); loop_it != begin(); --loop_it) { auto it = loop_it; --it; }`  Effectively, you iterator from `end()` to `begin()` but then inside of the loop you use the element that precedes the element pointed to by the iterator; if you draw this method out on paper, it'll make more sense than I can explain here in a comment :-P  (Replace `auto` with your iterator type)

Comment: @James: Ah, two iterators. Great, I think I can run with this. I'll save my dereferencing `reverse_iterator` compiler error for another time/question, unless you're really curious. Thanks for the explanation.